# Literally about meaning in a context

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm currently reading [**this article,**](https://www.yahoo.com/sports/michael-jordan-balled-drinking-maybe-205750111.html) and the first paragraph says,

> If you need another reason **(besides all the cool accolades, you know?)** to cement Michael Jordan as the GOAT, this is for you.

Will you kindly let me know what the bold part is trying to mean or trying to refer to?

I don't get it at all, especially about what the word "accolade" is referring to.

*If necessary, I would like to bring the another passage from the article.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**accolade** is recognition for something, often an award or verbal or written praise for someone's actions.

If you need another reason (besides all the cool accolades, you know?) to cement Michael Jordan as the GOAT, this is for you.

If you need another reason besides all the cool instances of praise about Michael Jordan etc.

In other words, Michael Jordan has received a lot of recognition (awards etc), if you need more than that, read the article.

cool is slang for great. I won't bother looking that up, it's very well known.

Generally: a word like cool, which is informal is not collocated with a word like accolade which is rather formal or literary.

The google dictionary gives this:

accolade
/ˈakəleɪd,ˌakəˈleɪd/
Learn to pronounce
noun
1.
an award or privilege granted as a special honour or as an acknowledgement of merit.
"the hotel has won numerous accolades"

Comment: May also be worth pointing out that GOAT is probably an acronym for Greatest Of All Time.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence is suggesting there are so many reasons why Jordon is the ‘goat’ but if that’s not enough you should read on and absorb the full article it is introducing. The bold text in parenthesis ending with a question mark I believe is your stumbling block. It is being a little sarcastic to the reader. It is actually saying (Jordon has so many accolades and you SHOULD know what they are, you do don’t you?) ... that’s why it is in bold.
The word accolade simply means achievements, either awards, records, firsts etc. It is a broad term to mean recognised accomplishments

Comment: Thank you for the additional info.